# Got "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" error in WebdriverIO javascript

Tags: async-await

Can someone help me on how to resolve this error? Got stucked here for 2 weeks and still haven't resolve this issue.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnGHM.png

Here's my code in the step definition:

```
Then(/^I should see the Centre homepage$/, async function () {
  const centre = await this.getTestData('westfieldCentre')
  const url = await (await centre.replace(/\s/g, '')).toLowerCase()
  await common.checkRedirectionUrl(`/${url}`, 'wevo')
  await universalHeader.checkUnvHdrModuleTitle(centre)
})
```

Comment: Provide context (stack, used libraries). Tag the question. Unless you use some unknown technology you run JavaScript and there are too many awaits in your code.

Comment: For the context, im using cucumber automation tool and the framework is WebdriverIO. I have this scenario that when the user search for a centre and that user clicks on that centre, user must be redirected to the centre homepage. I am able to redirect to the centre homepage, however, it seems it wasn't able to read the element that i used when checking the centre homepage title

Comment: Yes but I can not understand what different types should be. Is centre a `string`? If so, what are you doing here `await (await centre.replace(/\s/g, '')).toLowerCase()`?

Comment: Yes, centre is a string. This is where the list of locations(e.g. Belconnen, Sydney) are stored. For the centre.replace, it removes the whitespace for the centre.